# How to get the contents of rows from csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I tried to get some basic statistics of my columns in csv file, but apparently, I can't even get the contents of the columns in my output.

I tried `data['columnname']`

```
import pandas as p    
data = p.read_csv('Amazon.csv',delimiter='~}',na_values='nan')   
data.columns    
data['Title']
```

I expect to get the contents of 'Title' in my output

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of the .csv it's a bit hard, but hopefully something like this helps:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("Amazon.csv", ... , header=0)
```

Setting `header=0` will read the first line of the file and make it the column names.

If names aren't defined by the .csv you can either add them to the first line and use `header=0` or use `names=<array-like>`.

```py
data = pd.read_csv("Amazon.csv", ... , names=['Title',...,'LastCol'])
```

See: [Pandas Docs for read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)